# Como consumir um JSON em um webservice localhost com android studio

Tags: php, android, sql, json

Boa noite, então eu não sei se meu código está correto então por isso não tenho a certeza do por que não funciona, segue meu código no android studio

```html
package com.example.aplicativoderestaurante;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private TextInputEditText cep;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cep = findViewById(R.id.cep);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MyTask task = new MyTask();
                String numero = cep.getText().toString();
                String urlApi = "https://localhost/";
                task.execute(urlApi);

            }
        });

    }
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stringurl = strings[0];
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
            StringBuffer  buffer = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(stringurl);
                HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                inputStream = conexao.getInputStream();
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String linha = "";
                while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(linha);
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            String IDMOV = null;
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                IDMOV = jsonObject.getString("IDMOV");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textView.setText(IDMOV);
        }
    }
}
```

e segue meu código do webservice

```html
<?php
  $db = 'localhost:F:\Dados\TGA.FDB';
  $username = 'SYSDBA';
  $password = 'masterkey';
  // Connect to database

  $dbh = ibase_connect($db, $username, $password);
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TMOV WHERE IDMOV = 1974';
  // Execute query
  $rc = ibase_query($dbh, $sql);
  // Get the result row by row as object
  /* while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 
    foreach($row as $nomeColuna => $valorColuna) {
     echo $nomeColuna .": ". $valorColuna; // "NOMECOLUNAx: valorcolunax"
    }
  } */
  while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 
   /*  echo $row -> IDMOV, "\n"; // "NOMECOLUNAx: valorcolunax"
     echo $row -> CODFILIAL, "\n"; */
     echo json_encode($row);

  }
  // Release the handle associated with the result of the query
  ibase_free_result($rc);
  // Release the handle associated with the connection
  ibase_close($dbh);
 ?>
```

eu acesso o localhost e aparece os código em json certinho[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem quando aperto o botão que eu configurei para ele carregar o aplicativo crasha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema parece ser com a URL que você está usando para acessar o servidor. Note que localhost, do ponto de vista do aparelho que está rodando o app, é o próprio aparelho e não o servidor que você iniciou no seu computador.

Assim, há duas soluções que consigo pensar. Ao invés de "localhost":

1. Se você está testando o app **em um emulador**, utilize o endereço **10.0.2.2** (mais informações [aqui](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses)).
2. Se você está testando o app **em um smartphone físico**, acredito que utilizar o **IP do computador** resolva.

Comment: Boa noite, então fiz alguns teste, eu entrei no navegador pelo emulador, ele consegue acessar o endereço da API pelo navegador e pegar todos dados, só pelo aplicativo ele crasha quando eu tento rodar

Comment: Rapaz, mil desculpas pela demora. Se você ainda não encontrou uma solução, teria como incluir o stacktrace do erro na pergunta, por favor? Erros de _crash_ em apps Android geralmente são causados por alguma exceção que não foi tratada e "estourou" na execução. Pelo stacktrace, fica mais fácil identificar exatamente o ponto em que ela foi disparada (logo, a raiz do problema).

Comment: Eu consegui resolver, está faltando incluir a permissão se acesso a rede, eu não tinha me atentando no stack trace, que aparecia uma mensagem falando que não tinha permissão para se conectar ao ip local, muito obrigado pela ajuda.